# Idiom: своя в доску, но не доска

Tags: идиомы

I'm struggling to understand the meaning of this. Is it something like "it's what's inside that counts"?

Comment: This sounds like it was taken from a dating web site, am I right? ;)

Comment: Some girl had it as her tagline on Instagram and it threw me. I love/hate idioms.

Comment: ha ha... it's not just an idiom, it's just an ingenious idiomatic rhetoric :> The meaning see in the answer of Slepov, but - "свой в доску" means a "big friend", but "доска" in this context more means as "woman with very small breast",  not a "frigid woman". :>
the frigid woman will be a "timber", "бревно". :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Свой в доску" means 'a close friend', 'someone you can trust'. "Свой" is often opposed to "чужой" (us versus them) meaning "one of us" (whoever those 'us' may be). "В доску" is basically an intensifier, in line with similar slang expressions: "в дюпель", "в зюзю", "в дрыбаган", etc. "Свой в доску" is an idiom. It's also how they chose to translate the title of the film "[Soul Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_Man_(film))".

"Доска" (also "дерево", "бревно") are slang words for "frigid woman".

Those are two separate expressions put together for a comic effect.

Comment: "Доска" is about having no curves (comes from "плоская как доска" — "flat like a plank"), not about being frigid. At least in my experience.

Comment: @Alissa Absolutely. One particular component of the curves, I would say. From my experience :)

Comment: @Alissa, yes, that's a more probable explanation, thanks.

Comment: "свой в доску" means a "big friend", but "доска" in this context more means as "woman with very small breast",  not a just "frigid woman". :> the "frigid woman" is a бревно, a timber.